# Is it possible to select a random variable from a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is an example of something I want to do:

```
import random

class example_Class(object):

  def __init__(self, firstvar, secondvar, thirdvar):
    self.firstvar = firestvar
    self.secondvar = secondvar
    self.thirdvar = thirdvar

variable_1 = example(1, 2, 3)

variable_2 = example(4, 5, 6)

variable_3 = example(7, 8, 9)

random_var = (random.choice(example_Class))
```

Ideally, then, random_var would be assigned as equal to either variable_1, variable_2, and variable_3. But this doesn't work because I have no idea what the syntax for this would be. Any help?

Comment: keep values on list instead of separated variables. And then use `random.choice(class_instance.list_with_all_values)`

Comment: Using `random.choice` would require that your class be a sequence.

Comment: What is `example`, did you mean `example_Class`? And do you want `random_var` to become randomly one of the three `example_Class` objects or one of the three variables withing one of those objects? You question, as written, is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice` expects a sequence of some type. I would define a specific method to use to produce one from the data in your object.

```
 class ExampleClass:
     @property
     def values(self):
         return [self.firstvar, self.secondvar, self.thirdvar]
```

Then you can write

```
e = ExampleClass()
random_var = random.choice(e.values)
```